# Error from Azure when using request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, request-promise

I get this error from Azure when I'm trying to get/post with nodejs 'request-promise':

> Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
>   TypeError: Object function SafeBuffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) {
>   return Buffer(arg, encodingOrOffset, length) } has no method 'concat'
>       at Request. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1133:30)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:67:17)
>       at IncomingMessage. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:156:14)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
>       at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1288:20)
>       at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:375:27)
>       at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:734:20)
>       at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:130:13)
>       at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:367:14)

When I'm using the local express server I don't have any issues.

I also have a GET request using 'xhr2' and I don't get any issues from Azure.

Any ideas?

Thank you

edit:code added

```
 rp.get({
       uri: getFollowersURL,
       json: true,
       headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
       }).then(function (resultGetFollowers) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(resultGetFollowers.data.openid));
       });
```

Comment: Is this on version 1 or V2 of the Azure Functions runtime? can you show your code?

Comment: I'm not sure as i don't have any function apps.

Comment: my bad - are you running this in a regular web app?

Comment: yes, i am. It looks like azure it's not fine with request module.

Comment: I'm using the request module in Azure, so technically it should be working. Have you tried using a newer node version (can be set in the Application Settings)?